# Is there an easy way to copy the TDictionary content into another?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2, deep-copy, tdictionary

Is there a single method or easy way how to copy one TDictionary content into another ?
Let's say I have the following declarations

```
type
  TItemKey = record
    ItemID: Integer;
    ItemType: Integer;
  end;
  TItemData = record
    Name: string;
    Surname: string;
  end;
  TItems = TDictionary<TItemKey, TItemData>;

var
  // the Source and Target have the same types
  Source, Target: TItems;
begin
  // I can't find the way how to copy source to target
end;
```

and I would like to copy 1:1 the Source to Target. Is there such method for this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TDictionary has a constructor that allows you to pass in another collection object, which will create the new one by copying the contents of the original.  Is that what you are looking for?

```
constructor Create(Collection: TEnumerable<TPair<TKey,TValue>>); overload;
```

So you would use

```
Target := TItems.Create(Source);
```

And Target would be created as a copy of Source (or at least contain all the items in Source).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go even further, here's another approach:

```
type
  TDictionaryHelpers<TKey, TValue> = class
  public
    class procedure CopyDictionary(ASource, ATarget: TDictionary<TKey,TValue>);
  end;

...implementation...

{ TDictionaryHelpers<TKey, TValue> }

class procedure TDictionaryHelpers<TKey, TValue>.CopyDictionary(ASource,
  ATarget: TDictionary<TKey, TValue>);
var
  LKey: TKey;
begin
  for LKey in ASource.Keys do
    ATarget.Add(LKey, ASource.Items[ LKey ] );
end;
```

usage according to your definition of **Key** and **Value**:

```
TDictionaryHelpers<TItemKey, TItemData>.CopyDictionary(LSource, LTarget);
```

Comment: I thinks this woud be faster:
`var
  Item: TPair<TKey,TValue>;
...
for Item in ASource do
  ATarget.Add(Item.Key, Item.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var
  LSource, LTarget: TItems;
  LKey: TItemKey;
begin
  LSource := TItems.Create;
  LTarget := TItems.Create;
  try
    for LKey in LSource.Keys do 
      LTarget.Add(LKey, LSource.Items[ LKey ]);
  finally
    LSource.Free;
    LTarget.Free;
  end; // tryf
end;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you assign LNewKey := LKey; rather than just using Lkey twice in the expression LTarget.Add(LKey, LSource.Items[ LKey ]);

Comment: I thinks this woud be faster:
`var
  Item: TPair<TKey,TValue>;
...
for Item in LSource do
  ATarget.Add(Item.Key, Item.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a new instance when assignment is intended can have side effects, e.g. object reference invalidation elsewhere. Generic approaches may not deep copy referenced types.

I would go with a simpler approach:

```
unit uExample;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type 
  TStringStringDictionary = class(TDictionary<string,string>)
  public
    procedure Assign(const aSSD: TStringStringDictionary);
  end;

implementation

procedure TStringStringDictionary.Assign(const aSSD: TStringStringDictionary );
var
  lKey: string;
begin
  Clear;
  for lKey in aSSD.Keys do
    Add(lKey, aSSD.Items[lKey]); // Or use copy constructors for objects to be duplicated
end;

end.
```